# How to make a snapshot of ERC-721 (NFT) token holders

Tags: erc-721, nft, snapshot

What is the best way to create a snapshot of ERC-721 token holders? Maybe there is a tool for this purpose?

I need to take a snapshot of holders of tokens for this NFT contract - https://etherscan.io/address/0xd07dc4262bcdbf85190c01c996b4c06a461d2430

Comment: You are saying "snapshot" meaning an immutable list of token holders which you can then query as of that point in time. Right?

Comment: Welcome! The contract linked is actually an ERC1155 contract, meaning it can contain ERC20 and ERC721 type tokens. Can you clarify what you need a snapshot of?

Comment: Yes, I need an immutable list of ERC-721 holders to be able to query it and make an airdrop for all of them. Every user can holder several instances of the NFT token which is ERC-721 as I understand so I need also to have data about how many each user has. Thank you.

Comment: can you use the thegraph or some other indexer and setup a "watch" on that contract as a subgraph, then you could query it? I'm also interested in this, it seems most methods you have to listen for events.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm curious how snapshots work.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two options for taking snapshots of a ERC721 collection at a specific time.
https://dune.xyz/masroor/NFT-Holders-Snapshot
https://tools.roland.xyz/snapshot

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Tethrr.io for this - allows you to run snapshots without needing APIs.  I would give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

Can highly recommend Radiant Segment (https://segment.radiant.so) super easy to create segments and export a CSV or JSON file.